# App crashes when showing time and notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, datetime, time, parse-platform

My app is crashing when I create a new comment for a post with notifyDataSetChanged() that is linked to an adapter that shows time. All Data is taken from parse.com where I store all my database information. The freshly made comment is supposed to immediately shown in the listview in the same activity showing the comment and the time. The time is taken by createdAt() that is substracted by currentTime.

the error says:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.util.Date.getTime()' on a null object reference
```

and this is the button that will add the comment:

```
                            //Add a new comment
                            mAddComment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    Log.d("log", "add button clicked");

                                    final ParseObject myComment = new ParseObject("Comments");
                                    final String comment = mComment.getText().toString();
                                    myComment.put("CommentOwner", currentUserUsername);
                                    myComment.put("Comment", comment);
                                    myComment.put("SocialId", ParseObject.createWithoutData("Social", socialId));
                                    myComment.saveInBackground();

                                    adapter.setNotifyOnChange(false);
                                    adapter.add(myComment);
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                                    if (adapter.isEmpty()) {
                                    } else {
                                        mList.setSelection(mList.getAdapter().getCount() - 1);
                                    }
                                    mComment.setText("");
                                }
                            });
```

and this is the thing inside the adapter that shows the time:

```
    public SocialCommentAdapter(Context context, List<ParseObject> Comment) {
        super(context, R.layout.socialcommentcustomlayout, Comment);
            mContext = context;
            mComment = Comment;
    }
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    final ParseObject commentObject = mComment.get(position);
    //get Time
    Date created = commentObject.getCreatedAt();
    Date currentDate = new Date();


    long timepast = currentDate.getTime() - created.getTime(); <<<< The Error points to this line of the code

    long days = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(timepast);
    timepast -= TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(days);
    long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(timepast);
    timepast -= TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hours);
    long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(timepast);
    timepast -= TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(minutes);
    long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(timepast);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(64);
    if( days > 0){
        sb.append(days);
        sb.append("d");
    }else if (hours>0){
        sb.append(hours);
        sb.append("h");
    } else if (minutes >0){
        sb.append(minutes);
        sb.append("m");
    }else if ( seconds >0){
        sb.append(seconds);
        sb.append("s");
    }

    holder.timeComment.setText(sb.toString());
```

Do you guys know what's wrong with this? Can you guys help me out?

Thank you

Comment: `commentObject.getCreatedAt();` a few lines above your crash is returning null and so your `created` object is null, causing your crash. I'm not sure why `getCreatedAt()` is returning null. Maybe if you could post some more code where commentObject is initialized it would be more apparent.

Comment: I just added some lines of code. it doesn't really say much. I'm also not sure why it's null. it can get comment Strings, but not date. so weird. do you have a solution to do something like "if(date==null){holder.timeComment.setText("just now"); I tried doing something like this. but "==" is not compatible with long and null. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something that can be a solution for me.

I believe the problem is that created time is null.

so I solved this problem by creating an if/else method as follow:

```
    //get Time
    Date created = commentObject.getCreatedAt();
    Date currentDate = new Date();
    if( created == null ){
        holder.timeComment.setText("just now");
    }else{

        long timepast = currentDate.getTime() - created.getTime();

        long days = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(timepast);
        timepast -= TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(days);
        long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(timepast);
        timepast -= TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hours);
        long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(timepast);
        timepast -= TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(minutes);
        long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(timepast);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(64);
        if( days > 0){
            sb.append(days);
            sb.append("d");
        }else if (hours>0){
            sb.append(hours);
            sb.append("h");
        } else if (minutes >0){
            sb.append(minutes);
            sb.append("m");
        }else if ( seconds >0){
            sb.append(seconds);
            sb.append("s");
        }

        holder.timeComment.setText(sb.toString());

    }
```

This way, if it cannot get the created time, it will just say "just now". this works well for me.

Answer (score 2):

*I know you just answered your own question, but I was in the middle of writing my answer and wanted to add an explanation as to **why** your variable is null, so I'll just post my answer anyway.*

First of all, `commentObject.getCreatedAt();` a few lines above your crash is returning null and so your `created` object is null, and that is the cause of your crash. Now for an explanation.

[Reading the documentation on `getCreatedAt()`](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#getCreatedAt()), we see that it returns the time which will be

> ...the creation time will be the time of the first ParseObject.save() call rather than the time the object was created locally.

Now, we can see that you have called `myComment.saveInBackground();` in your onClick method on a new ParseObject, and added that object to a list. You then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` which triggers the getView method where your code is crashing. Your saveInBackground method should save the object, but, it is going to do it in the background... a different thread from the thread you are creating the object on.

So the way I understand the documentation and what we are seeing here, `getCreatedAt()` will return null until the ParseObject is saved, at which time it will return the Date object with the correct data. Because you are calling `saveInBackground` instead of `save`, the saving happens on a background thread, which means that the saving probably doesn't happen right away. The execution order is as follows:

1. You Initialize the ParseObject
2. You call saveInBackground on the object, saving probably hasn't started yet
3. You add the object to your adapter and call notify
4. getView gets triggered and your app crashes because the Date is still null
5. Maybe around here (in some cases earlier) the save will be complete and Date won't be null anymore if your app doesn't crash.

The way you can fix it is by checking if the variable is null:

```
if (created != null) {
    long timepast = currentDate.getTime() - created.getTime();
    .
    . // your date forming code here
    .
    holder.timeComment.setText(sb.toString());
} else {
    holder.timeComment.setText("new");
}
```

Hope this helps explain why you were getting a null object.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It all makes sense now. Based on your answer, the solution you provided is the same with my solution. You also mentioned about .save() and .saveinbackground(). does it mean if I saved my comments with .save() instead of .saveinbackground() it will solve null CreatedAt()? I didn't know .save() exist.

Comment: @stanleysantoso yes! you did find the correct solution. I believe if you call .save() instead of .saveInBackground() it will block the UI (app might freeze for a second as it makes the network call) but it should save and then return a usable date object.

Comment: thank you. I tried writing .save() but apparently it's not an existing method since the word get red underlined.

Comment: @stanleysantoso it's a valid method, wrap it in a `try{...}catch(ParseException e){...}` as the method throws a ParseException https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#save()